# How to get rid of extra characters in linux process ID using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command, pid

I m trying to kill a process by its pid, and this is the script that I found from web.

```
PID=`ps -ef | grep myProcess | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`  
echo -e Killing myProcess with pid: $PID..
```

Output: Killing myProcesswith pid: 13275^M..

Does anyone know why is there a ^M , how do I get rid of that because the kill command failed to run :

```
**arguments must be process or job IDs**
```

I searched online but still got no idea how to overcome this..
Any help is appreciated!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

first, your syntax is wrong. Use `$()` to call a command and store its output to variable

```
PID=$(ps -ef | grep myProcess | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
```

second, you can do this all in one `awk` statement without the need for extra `grep` processes.

```
ps -eo pid,args | awk '/myProces[s]/{cmd="kill  "$1;print cmd; }'
```

Answer (score 0):

From a [quick read online](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Printing), the print command to awk always appends a newline (which can sometimes be represented by Control-M, or ^M).

It would appear that printf would be a suitable alternative. Maybe:

```
PID=ps -ef | grep myProcess | grep -v grep | awk '{printf "%i",$2}'
```

Comment: @kurumi - sorry, I'm not able to test it at the moment - what do I need to adjust?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you dont want to kill a process by PID, by its name. And you do it by getting the process PID and then try to kill it via PID. If you want to kill by name, use `killall processname`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use :

```
PID=`pidof myProcess`
```